# Excel formulas for range criteria date, arranged in columns

Tags: excel, sumifs

I want to write a formula for a large data chart. The criteria which I have to choose is on rows and columns.

I attach the file with the manually written calculus.

```
|PRODUCT|01-feb|02-feb|03-feb|04-feb|05-feb|06-feb|07-feb|08-feb|09-ef|10-feb|11-feb|feb-12|
|PRODUCT 1|4|3|1|5|2|9|1|3|5|8|0|5|
|PRODUCT 3|2|5|7|4|4|8|3|5|7|4|4|8|
|PRODUCT 1|1|0|5|3|1|1|8|0|5|3|1|1|
|PRODUCT 2|5|4|6|6|0|7|4|4|6|6|0|7|
|PRODUCT 5|8|7|8|7|1|9|2|7|8|7|1|9|
|PRODUCT 4|4|2|9|3|5|1|7|2|9|3|5|1|
|PRODUCT 1|9|8|1|4|4|6|5|8|1|4|4|6|
|PRODUCT 2|6|4|4|7|2|8|6|4|4|7|2|8|
|PRODUCT 5|2|6|1|8|3|9|3|6|1|8|3|9|
|PRODUCT 3|3|9|5|1|7|4|7|9|5|1|7|4|
|PRODUCT 4|7|6|5|5|8|2|1|6|5|5|8|2|
```

The compact chart that I have to get:

```
|PRODUCT|04-feb|08-feb|12-feb|
|PRODUCT 1|44|48|43|
|PRODUCT 2|42|35|40|
|PRODUCT 3|36|47|40|
|PRODUCT 4|41|32|38|
|PRODUCT 5|47|40|46|
```

The formula that it should works:

```
=SUMAR.SI.CONJUNTO(C5:N15,B5:B15,H20,C4:N4,"=<"&J19)
```

because I want to show a range of date between `01-feb` to `04-feb` from the first chart in the new column `04-feb`.

Please, help me.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following might help you. The formula in the upper left cell of the table of the summary is

```
 {=SUM((($B$1:$M$1<=B$14)*($B$1:$M$1>=A$14)*$B$2:$M$13)*($A15=$A$2:$A$13))}
```

and can be copied over to the over cells. The 31.01 in the summary table is used as a "helper cell", so that you don't have to alter the formula for the different cells.

```
  Product   01. Feb 02. Feb 03. Feb 04. Feb 05. Feb 06. Feb 07. Feb 08. Feb 09. Feb 10. Feb 11. Feb 12. Feb
Product1    5   2   3   3   5   5   3   3   5   3   3   5
Product3    5   4   2   4   5   1   5   3   3   5   3   3
Product4    3   1   2   2   4   5   5   1   5   5   1   5
Product1    4   1   4   3   4   1   4   1   3   4   1   3
Product3    1   2   2   4   5   2   5   1   1   5   1   1
Product4    3   2   4   1   1   4   3   5   2   3   5   2
Product1    4   3   5   1   1   1   2   2   2   2   2   2
Product3    3   2   4   3   5   1   1   1   4   1   1   4
Product4    2   1   4   2   2   1   4   4   3   4   4   3
Product1    4   5   5   2   3   4   3   4   5   3   4   5
Product3    4   2   3   1   4   1   1   3   1   1   3   1
Product4    3   5   3   3   1   4   1   1   3   1   1   3



31. Jan 04. Feb 08. Feb 12. Feb                                 
Product1    54  55  62                                  
Product2    0   0   0                                   
Product3    46  56  46                                  
Product4    41  54  61                                  
Product5    0   0   0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use sumproduct for this. B2:E12 is the range of data for Feb 1 though Feb 4, and O2 is equal to the criteria you are searching for. So in my case O2 was equal to Product 1. When you want the range for Feb 8, just change B2:E12 to the range of data corresponding to Feb 5 to Feb 8.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(B2:E12*(A2:A12=O2))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but how can I include the criteria in the rows?

Comment: the criteria is equal to to your row label. In your case if you are searching for the Sum of Product 1, your criteria cell would be the row label "Product 1" 

Based on your picture looks like G18 is your criteria for Product 1 and so on.